# List the cities that have received shipment for every customer

Tags: sql, oracle, mysqli

```
CUSTOMER (cust_id, cust_name, annual_revenue)
SHIPMENT (shipment_id, cust_id, weight, truck_no, dest)
TRUCK (truck_no, driver_name)
CITY (city_name, population)

select s.dest from shipment s
where not exists (
  (select cust_id from customer)
    except
  (select ss.cust_id from customer ss where ss.dest = s.dest)
);
```

giving error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Why???

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the requirement - do you want to find cities where there are zero outstanding deliveries? It would seem that there should be some kind of status indicator on a shipment so that we can tell whether it has been fulfilled or not?

Comment: want to list all the cities that have received shipment for every customer.

Comment: Remove the parentheses around the two EXCEPT selects?

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite it as:

```
select dest
from shipment
group by dest
having count(distinct cust_id) = (select count(*) from customer)
```

It's a bit easier to understand and will perform better because it doesn't use any correlated subqueries.